# running function when underscore each ends

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I'm using `_.each` from underscore lib, and I wonder if there is any option to know if the the loop ended his job ? I want to create a function that will run **only** when `_.each` ends his job and done all the array.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loop runs asynchronous code, which it probably does because you are asking this question, you can save yourself some of time by looking into a control flow library like [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It's packed with functions to handle situations just like this. For your current problem you should look into [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) or [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback)

I would advice you to take a look at the source code of the async functions you are using... they are not that complex and it's good to understand how they work.

If your loop doesn't run asynchronous code, whatever you place after the loop will be exectued in order when the loop is finished... =P

Answer (score 1):

Usually for each runs synchronous only. If you need more confirmation. Just check for that array length..